# Refresh the popup input text in Angular 9

Tags: angular

I have added a popup for adding the new user activity... with one input box for adding a activity in the popup after submitting the activity the input box is not refreshing ...

need help ...
I am new to this

I have below code in **component.html**

```
 <div class="usermanagement modal fade" id="cloneactivity" tabindex="-3" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
         <div class="modal-content">
            <form  (ngSubmit)="Addnew()">
               <div class="modal-header">
                  <h4 class="modal-title">User Activity</h4>
                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
               </div>
               
               <div class="modal-body">
                  <p>Are you sure you want to add the activity?</p>
                  <!-- <label
                  class="col-form-label"> :
               </label> -->
               New activity : <input type="text" class="formControl" Id="newactivity" placeholder=" activity Name"> 
              
               </div>
            

               
               
               <div class="modal-footer">
                  <input type="button" class="btn-cancel" data-dismiss="modal" #closecloneResourceModal
                     value="Cancel">
                  <input type="submit" class="btn-submit" value="Clone">

           </div>
        </form>
```

and in **Addnew()**

```
Addnew() {
    console.log(" user ID :" + this.userId);
   this.onaddnewactivity(this.userId);
this.closeResourceModal.nativeElement.click();

     }
```

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: Hi Nandini, welcome to Stackoverflow! for other users to be able to help you. it's recommended that you post more details on how one could reproduce the issue you're going through. Please add more details to your question such as the code you're using or even a snippet where people can see exactly the problem.

Comment: Hello, added the code snippet , @Gabcvit